# Send Response Entity Gateway API ( Adapter port out) to Controller Input API with Clean Architecture

Tags: java, spring-boot, clean-architecture

I'm trying to develop a project JAVA based on Clean Architecture,

I have an API Input with Request Update who call application service.

This Application service call the Adapter Out (External Gateway) because I need to call an External API for get some information before complete operations.

Let me show you a little bit of the code to better understand:

**Controller API :**

```
@PostMapping(path = "/update/info")
void updateInfo(@RequestBody Info request) {
Info info = new Info(request.getXXX());
updateInfoUseCase.updateInfo(info);
}
```

In the application package, I have an interface for implemnts this use case, and I have in
Adapter out (where located the External API GATEWAY) and I have something like this:

**External Gateway API (Adapter OUT)**

```
@Override
public void updateInfo(String info) {
//Here i need to call several times external API with RestTemplate
}
}
```

My question is if the external API response failed or cannot update info, how can I send the response to the API Input for the user client?

I really hope to find some help, I hope my example is clear enough

Answer (score 0):

You can use this solution:

The method in you Controller Class:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/update/info")
ResponseEntity<Object> updateInfo(@RequestBody Info request) {
     Info info = new Info(request.getXXX());
     try {
         Object res = updateInfoUseCase.updateInfo(info);
         return ResponseEntity.ok().body(res);
     }catch (RestClientException e){
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_MODIFIED).body(e);
     } 
}
```

The Method that call External API

```
@Override
public Objcet updateInfo(String info) {
  RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
  return restTemplate.postForObject(URL, request, Object.class);
}
```

If you want you can **use** **`@RestControllerAdvice`** to centralize handeler error and manage the response in case KO like this case.